# What decides if a 'too chatty' flag results in immediate deletion?

Tags: support, flagging, comments

I just flagged a comment as 'obsolete, chatty' on Music Practise, where I only have under 5k rep, & the comment immediately went... boom, gone.

I've seen it happen on SU & Ask Different too, but most times it just adds a little red flag & the outcome is decided later.

What mechanism makes it just go 'boom' with no review process?

Could it be that I was coincidentally the deciding flag & others had done it before, but the flag isn't shown unless it's your flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most likely that the comment contained some key phrases which enabled it for deletion by only one flag, as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/295232). E.g. a comment containing just

> +1, thank you very much

will probably be deleted after just a single comment flag.

Comment: That could be it. I don't remember the exact wording in this particular case, but it was along the lines of "Can you please help me find an answer to this?" posted by the OP directly underneath their own question, 2 minutes after the OP itself.